# NFS not working on bonded NFS interface - mount.nfs: No such device

Tags: centos, redhat, nfs, mount, rhel6

We have an error message when trying to mount NFS on a RHEL server.

NFS works fine on all our other servers, but not on 2 freshly kickstarted servers with the error "mount.nfs: No such device".

```
[root@tst-03 ~]# mount -o udp -t nfs 192.168.10.19:/export/install/pkgs/other/ /mnt
mount.nfs: No such device
[root@tst-03 ~]# showmount -e 192.168.10.19
Export list for 192.168.10.19:
/export/install         (everyone)
[root@tst-03 ~]# lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
bluetooth              99548  0
rfkill                 19735  1 bluetooth
bonding               125610  0
bridge                 79790  0
stp                     2173  1 bridge
llc                     5642  2 bridge,stp
nfsd                  305799  13
lockd                  74270  1 nfsd
nfs_acl                 2647  1 nfsd
auth_rpcgss            44895  1 nfsd
exportfs                4236  1 nfsd
sunrpc                243758  17 nfsd,lockd,nfs_acl,auth_rpcgss
pcc_cpufreq             5090  0
ipv6                  322029  185 bonding
hpilo                   7865  0
hpwdt                   7094  0
power_meter             9343  0
microcode             112594  0
tg3                   140819  0
serio_raw               4818  0
sg                     30124  0
iTCO_wdt               13662  0
iTCO_vendor_support     3088  1 iTCO_wdt
ioatdma                58482  160
dca                     7197  1 ioatdma
shpchp                 33482  0
ext4                  364410  5
mbcache                 8144  1 ext4
jbd2                   88738  1 ext4
sd_mod                 39488  3
crc_t10dif              1541  1 sd_mod
sr_mod                 16228  0
cdrom                  39771  1 sr_mod
hpsa                   52017  2
qla2xxx               366337  0
scsi_transport_fc      52241  1 qla2xxx
scsi_tgt               12173  1 scsi_transport_fc
pata_acpi               3701  0
ata_generic             3837  0
ata_piix               22846  0
dm_mirror              14101  0
dm_region_hash         12170  1 dm_mirror
dm_log                 10122  2 dm_mirror,dm_region_hash
dm_mod                 81500  17 dm_mirror,dm_log
[root@tst-03 log]# modinfo nfs
filename:       /lib/modules/2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64/kernel/fs/nfs/nfs.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Olaf Kirch <okir@monad.swb.de>
srcversion:     666B7C399EC7E374CAD721B
depends:        sunrpc,fscache,lockd,auth_rpcgss,nfs_acl
vermagic:       2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64 SMP mod_unload modversions
parm:           callback_tcpport:portnr
parm:           cache_getent:Path to the client cache upcall program (string)
parm:           cache_getent_timeout:Timeout (in seconds) after which the cache upcall is assumed to have failed (ulong)
parm:           enable_ino64:bool
[root@tst-03 log]# uname -a
Linux tst-03 2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Nov 9 08:03:13 EST 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Please let me know if I have to provide additional information!

Comment: Do you have the portmapper running?  Check for a process called `portmap`.

Comment: No, I do not have portmapper running, but I don't have it running on other servers either, where NFS works just fine.

Comment: Try to mount base on the export list: "mount -o udp -t nfs 192.168.10.19:/export/install /mnt"

Comment: did you try and do the same exact command on the other servers, where you said the nfs works fine.

Comment: Yes, the exact same command!

Comment: Try to run "modprobe nfs" as root and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a bond interface named "nfs", and this was causing the issue. I had to change the bond alias name to something else rather than "nfs" (preferably bond0) because when you are trying to load the nfs module (which is done automatically when you run the mount command) you are passing "mode=active-backup miimon=100" as parameters to the nfs module, which are not accepted.

I had  to follow these steps:

1. ifdown nfs
2. Change the alias name at bonding.conf
3. Change the bond name on the physical interfaces
4. ifup new_interface_name